# How to order by largest number

Tags: mysql

I've got a pretty simple question, I think..

I've got a database field that stores the byte size of files. I want to order by the largest file_size, but it's not working as I'd hoped...

I've tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM file_data
ORDER BY file_size DESC
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM file_data
ORDER BY MAX( file_size ) DESC
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

The reason it's not working as expected is because these are the results from the first query:

```
ID    file_size
13    980616    
200    9782897  
199    9732752  
187    967006   
166    9614688  
12    9481028   
44    945120    
65    9228440   
208    92140357
```

Comment: Your first query seems fine; post your table definition and some of your records so we can understand what's happening. Is `file_size` field an integer?

Comment: why is it not working? - your first query should do it - if file_size is some kind of numeric data and not some char, varchar, etc

Comment: What results are you getting at the moment? A small sample of data would help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The `ORDER BY file_size` will sort by the `file_size` column. If that's not what you want, can you explain more specifically what "order by largest file_size" means?

Comment: what's the data type of "files_size" column?

Comment: What is not working? Is it in the wrong order or is the query just not working?
The first query should work

Comment: What kind of results are you seeing?  The first query you have should work.  The second query only makes sense if you also have the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: It was the data type, I didn't check, and it was varchar. I converted to integer and it's perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if `file_size` is a CHAR/VARCHAR field probably the result is not what you expected (edit: in support of my thesis, the resultset you posted seems to be alphabetically sorted)

So try to change the column data type to INTEGER or, if you cannot alter the table, make an explicit casting in your query using

```
SELECT * 
FROM file_data
ORDER BY CAST(file_size AS INTEGER) DESC
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: This is the reason. Thanks. It was varchar(255) when it should have been integer.

Comment: if possible, it would be much better to convert the table structure to something more performant: `ALTER TABLE file_data MODIFY file_size INT`

Comment: I did convert it to integer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`CAST` or `CONVERT` should solve your problem

```
SELECT * 
FROM file_data
ORDER BY CONVERT(file_size,INTEGER) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code should work, try changing the column data type to INTEGER or make an explicit casting in your query using.